# How can I provide proof to a Visa Officer that I transferred funds one account of mine to another?

Tags: banking, visa

I have two accounts in my name in two different banks. My primary bank was not cooperating with me to send money overseas to a school for my masters degree. Instead of arguing with them, I transferred the funds to my secondary account and wired the funds from there.

To transfer the funds from my primary account to my secondary account, I wrote a cheque. The bank statement clearly shows the transaction occurring on the same date for the amount I wrote but the secondary bank has a remark in the statement saying "From Acc. No. - XXX" where XXX is presumably the sender's (i.e. my other account number) - except the number listed does not match my primary account number (from where I transferred the funds).

In order to obtain a student visa, I must submit my bank statements. My worry is that the Visa Officer will note that the account numbers don't match and ban me for misrepresentation.

How can I prove to the visa officer that I really did transfer the funds between my two accounts?

Comment: Is the "From XXX" a portion of the account number?  For privacy reasons (e.g. people pulling the statement out of your trash after you put it outside) the whole number is generally not listed.

Comment: It is not a portion. No portion of the number matches anywhere.

Comment: Do you have paperwork from the sending account that shows both account numbers?   BTW, this question seems more about what is acceptable to visa and passport control than financial decisions, so it might get better answers at [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Better check at expatriates.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can request cashed cheque from your bank. That should be sufficient proof.

Comment: What is a cashed cheque? Can you provide some detail?

Comment: That means a copy/image of the cheque.  Banks make an image scan of checks before they destroy them, and then they preserve the images on a big database.  Your bank should cheerfully provide a copy, and if your bank has any sort of web/online service, you may be able to view and print it online.